# why the largest value of $k$ for any number of the form $^<B$ is $\lfloor\log B \rfloor$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

Given an integer $n>2$, let $B=\lceil\log^5n\rceil$. I am trying to understand why the largest value of $k$ for any number of the form $m^k \le B$, $m\ge2$ is $\lfloor\log B \rfloor$.
Logarithms are in base $2$. It seems easy but I can't prove it.
Any hint would be precious, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you check your write up? EG Do you mean $ B = \lceil \log ^ 5 n \rceil$?  If yes, what is $n$?

Comment: And what is the relation between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: I don't think that there is a relation.